# Div parent and two children, get id of one children in other children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'd like get the id of my svg in jquery , I try this jquery but it's undefined.

```
$(event.target).children('svg').attr("id")
```

Target.event return data of p, when I look inside parent I have mmy column :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="zone" >
          <svg id="graphItem0_2" with="300" height="300"></svg>
          <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="position: absolute;  top: 300px; right:20px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have many svg element in my page when I try $(svg).attr("id"), I get just the first element but when I click on a other svg it's the same id then my other svg have not the same id.

Comment: Where is your event handler?

Comment: Check what is returned by `event.target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attach event click to the parent div `zone` then search for the svg using jQuery object `$(this)` instead :

```
$('.zone').on('click',function(){
  alert( $(this).find('svg').attr("id") );
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.zone').on('click',function(){
  alert( $(this).find('svg').attr("id") );
})
```

```css
.zone{
  background-color: red;
}
svg{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zone" >
  <svg id="graphItem0_2" with="300" height="300"></svg>
  <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="position: absolute;  top: 300px; right:20px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but I use meteor.js and my click zone call a function yet. if I try the click with p is undefined , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to something Like this.

```
$(".zone").click(function(){
  var id = $("svg").attr("id");
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: it was very simple! Thank you!! I'm a beginner in jquery, thanks !

Comment: Note that this would only work if there is one SVG on the page. And would get any SVG on the page no matter whether it was inside the clicked region or not. Zakaria's solution is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :-

```
var x = document.getElementById("svg").id;
```

It will work good if there is only 1 svg element on page.

Comment: I use with meteor.js and I have a error with id  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`